# Why doesn't this Regex operation work?

Tags: c#, regex

```
        string input = "They ate a donut", output = "a donut was eaten by ${someone}.";
        Regex r = new Regex("(?<someone>) ate a donut");
        if (r.IsMatch(input))
        {
            foreach (string s in r.GetGroupNames())
            {
                    Debug.WriteLine(r.Replace(input, output));
            }
        }
```

Context is that output should display "a donut was eaten by They", but instead I get "Theya donut was eaten by ."

And I'm not really sure why, because I keep looking up how substitutions work and it seems like this would.

Lastly, while not a big deal, shouldn't there only be one iteration of the loop since there is only one named group in the Regex r? I get two lines of the previously mentioned output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is that `(?<someone>)` doesn't capture anything. It's a named group, but a group needs to contain something to match or it'll just match the empty string. Thus you are replacing `" ate a donut"` with `"a donut was eaten by "`, and leaving the `"They"` prefix.

Replace `(?<someone>)` with e.g. `(?<someone>\w+)` and you should capture a word (one or more of A-Z, a-z, 0-9 or underscores). Note that, to write a `\` in a C# string literal, you either need to write `\\` or you need to start your string with `@"` instead of just `"`.

Also, there's two iterations of the loop because the entire match counts as group "0" - so you have group "0" and group "someone".

Comment: That worked, thanks! I thought just the capture group being there would capture any remaining characters. Now I feel somewhat silly :l

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?<someone>\S+).*$
```

Try this.Replace by `a donut was eaten by ${someone}.`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/62

Comment: `?P` is not valid in .NET regular expressions. You've also added anchors and replaced meaningful text with `.*` for no reason.